# ag-grid - Tree data feature/ Group rows for Angular 2 like in javascript?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am working on `Angular 2` app using `ag-grid`. I am looking for [Tree data](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree/#gsc.tab=0) feature just like shown in the link for `javascript`. Or any other solution in Angular 2 using ag-grid.

**Question -**

Please let me know if there is any way to group rows in `ag grid - Angular 2` as seen in below sample -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Within your colDefs, you need two properties to be set:

```
showRowGroup: true,
cellRenderer: 'group'
```

Apply this to the column definition and you should see the expanding icon beside it.